# place a three.js sceen inside bootstrap grid

Tags: javascript, three.js

I try to understand how to embed three.js scene with few toggles inside of a bootstrap grid, for some reason my canvas which is inside column refuse to be in same row with the text column and i cant figure out why, any help will be much appreciated.

Preview: https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/Phoreaka/PlateInGrid/blob/master/index.html

Html:

```html
<section id="intro">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 textContainer ">
                    <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
                  
                  </div> <!-- col end -->
                  
                  
                  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
                      <div id="myCanvas"></div>
                  
                        <button id="polychrome"></button>
                        <button id="blue"></button>
                        <button id='PausePlay'>Pause</button>
                      
                  </div> <!-- col end --->
                  
              </div> <!--row end -->
          </div> <!-- container end -->
      </section>
```

Css:

```css
html, body {
    direction: rtl;
 font-family: 'Heebo', sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 margin: 0px;
 overflow: hidden;
}



.background {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -99;
    background-color: lightgray;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    
}

#intro {
    width: 100wh;
    height: 100%;
}

.textContainer {
    height: auto;
    font-size: 22px;
}

#myCanvas {
    
}

canvas {
    height: 0;
}



#polychrome {
    background-color: rgba(246, 244, 231, 1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #194E9F;
    
}

#blue {
    background-color: rgba(246, 244, 231, 1);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #194E9F;
}

#PausePlay {
    background-color: transparent;
    bottom: 20px;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Javascript:

```js
var container, stats, plate, plateTwo;

            //loading objects into scene
            var camera, scene, renderer, plate, plateTwo, controls; //loading objects into scene

            canvas_width = 700,
            canvas_height = 700;



            //Pause button toggle-Boolean for start and restart
            var initAnim = true;
            var runAnim = false;
            var isPlay = true;




            //tweening

            init();
            animate();


            //init functions for all the scene
            function init() {

                container = document.getElementById( 'myCanvas' ); //creates div and inside of it canvas
                document.body.appendChild( container );


                // scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();  

                //camera
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 40,canvas_width / canvas_height, 100, 100000 );
                camera.position.set( 0, 0, 1000 );


                //lights
                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xFFFFf3, 1.1 );
                ambient.position.set( 0, 0, 900 ).normalize();
                scene.add( ambient );
                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.6 );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 700 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );
                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.6 );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, -700 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                //lights end



                //setting renderer
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
                    alpha: true});//background opacity
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( canvas_width, canvas_height );
                document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

                //setting render end

                //orbit controls
                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
                controls.target = new THREE.Vector3(-300,0,0);
                controls.minPolarAngle = 1; // radians
                controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI/2; // radians
                controls.minDistance = 500;
                controls.maxDistance = 800;
                controls.enablePan = false;
                //orbit controls end


                // model blue
                    var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                        console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                    }
                };
                var onError = function ( xhr ) { };
                THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() ); //helper for texture loading

                //texture loader
                var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                mtlLoader.crossOrigin = ''; //cross origin-allows to run it on github
                mtlLoader.setPath( 'images/new/' );
                mtlLoader.load( 'BluePlate.mtl', function( materials ) {
                materials.preload();

                //model loader
                var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoader.setPath( 'images/new/' );
                objLoader.load( 'BluePlate.obj', addPlate);
                });


                //object position setings
                var addPlate = function(object){
                plate = object;
                plate.name = 'blue_plate';
                //Move the plate in the scene
                plate.rotateX(0);
                plate.rotateY(0);
                plate.rotateZ(30);
                plate.position.x = -300;
                plate.position.y = 0;
                plate.position.z = 0;
                plate.scale.y = 1.8;
                plate.scale.x = 1.8;
                plate.scale.z = 1.8;

                //Add the 3D object in the scene

                scene.add(plate);//adds the plate
                animate(plate);
                render();
                };

                //model blue end


                //model Polychrome inside of button function appears only when "#polychrome is pressed"

                    var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
                    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
                        var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
                        console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
                    }
                };
                var onError = function ( xhr ) { };
                THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader() ); //helper for texture loading

                //texture loader
                var mtlLoaderTwo = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                mtlLoaderTwo.crossOrigin = ''; //cross origin-allows to run it on github
                mtlLoaderTwo.setPath( 'images/new/' );
                mtlLoaderTwo.load( 'PolychromePlate.mtl', function( materials ) {
                materials.preload();


                //model loader
                var objLoaderTwo = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                objLoaderTwo.setMaterials( materials );
                objLoaderTwo.setPath( 'images/new/' );
                objLoaderTwo.load( 'PolychromePlate.obj', addPlateTwo);
                });


                //object position setings
                var addPlateTwo = function(object){
                plateTwo = object;
                plateTwo.name = "color_plate";
                //Move the plate in the scene
                plateTwo.rotateX(0);
                plateTwo.rotateY(0);
                plateTwo.rotateZ(30);
                plateTwo.position.x = -300;
                plateTwo.position.y = 0;
                plateTwo.position.z = 0;
                plateTwo.scale.y = 1.8;
                plateTwo.scale.x = 1.8;
                plateTwo.scale.z = 1.8;
                }    

                //polychrome model end


                //Add the 3D object in the scene 
                var changeTexture = function(){
                if(!(scene.getObjectByName('color_plate')))
                   {       
                    scene.remove(plate);//removes the blue plate from scene
                    scene.add(plateTwo);
                    animate(plateTwo);
                    render();
                   }

                };


                //function for button blue to switch back to blue texture
                function changeTextureBlue(){
                   if(!(scene.getObjectByName('blue_plate')))
                   {       
                   scene.add(plate);
                    scene.remove(plateTwo);//removes the polychrome
                   }
                }



                //mouse click - running the functions of button click need to appear after the model load
                document.getElementById('polychrome').addEventListener('click', changeTexture, false);
                document.getElementById('blue').addEventListener('click', changeTextureBlue, false);
                //mouse click end

                //pause toggle
                var startButton = document.getElementById( 'PausePlay' );

                // Start Button
                startButton.onclick = function StartAnimation() {

                    // Start and Pause 
                    if (runAnim) { 
                        startButton.innerHTML = 'Pause';
                        runAnim = false;
                        isPlay = true;
                        animate();
                    } else {
                        startButton.innerHTML = 'Play';
                        runAnim = true;
                        isPlay = false;

                    }
                }//pause toggle end




            } // init ends



            //settings for window resize

                function onWindowResize() {

                camera.aspect = canvas_width / canvas_height;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( canvas_width, canvas_height );

            }  //window resize settings end





            //animate function
            function animate() {
                if (!isPlay) return;
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                if ( plate !== undefined) {
                    plate.rotation.y += -.001; 
                };

                if ( plateTwo !== undefined ) {
                    plateTwo.rotation.y += -.001; 
                };


                render();
                controls.update();


                } //animate function end



            //render
            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera ); 

            } //render end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not adding your renderer to the div.
you have this:

```
container = document.getElementById( 'myCanvas' );
document.body.appendChild( container );
// then later..
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

You code is...
getting a reference to myCanvas,
Moving myCanvas div to be the last element in the body,
Then adding the renderer canvas as the last element in the body (which will be after the myCanvas div).

What you probably want it this:

```
// Get a reference to the container div
container = document.getElementById( 'myCanvas' );
// Add the renderer.domElement, which is a canvas, to the container div.
container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```